# Disabling the initiation form when workflow is started manually in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, custom-action

I have a sharepoint site(sharepoint 2010).

I have created a custom action, on click of which will initiate the workflow associated to a list. When the user clicks on the custom action button, an initiation form will be shown which will have the Start and Cancel button. Only on click of this Start button, the workflow will Run. I want to avoid the last step of clicking on the Start button. What I want is "On click of Custom action, Workflow should Run. Initiation form should not come into picture at all". Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two solutions:

1. Say it's good because you make sure the user didn't make a mistake
2. Change the custom action form to a page where you start the workflow manually (via code) and then redirect the user to the home screen (you can also do that with a dialog and then there's no need for redirect)